# Pulling my profile picture from Twitter using Auth/twitter4j/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, twitter, oauth

I'm looking to build a web service using [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/) which will allow me to get my profile picture from twitter and print it out somewhere.

My initial plan is to use Eclipse and Heroku/Git. I'm just a little unsure of the steps to take to accomplish this... I'm in no way new to coding or Heroku/Git, but I am fairly rusty when it comes to Java, and Java is the language I need to use.

Would anyone be able to suggestions how I would go creating the service I have mentioned above?

I have even cloned these 4 example web services [here](http://java.heroku.com/) to my desktop and then opened them in Eclipse, with the intention of changing/removing/adding whatever code I needed to in order to accomplish my task but I get endless

```
'Cannot be resolved to a type'
```

errors. I'm assuming this is because I need to install libraries/JAR files in my Java project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Twitter API if all you want is the user's image.

You can use a service like http://avatars.io/

Simply call http://avatars.io/twitter/edent to get my avatar.